# metro app Frame.Back() crashes the app

Tags: c#, frame, microsoft-metro

After I upgraded to VS2012 using `Frame.Back()` crashes the app. It also happens with the back button that VS creates when you add a basic page.

Comment: How does your code look like? I guess an empty history stack would throw an exception which, when uncaught, exits your app.

Comment: There have been a huge number of changes with the latest release of VS2012RC/Windows 8 RC.  Have you read the code migration document?   [Migrating Consumer Preview App to Release Preview](http://aka.ms/rpdevdoc)